# How to access mysql console on Docker container using secrets

Tags: docker, encryption, mariadb, docker-compose

I've been able to access Mysql console on a Mariadb Docker container.

From my local machine I can run this command to access the console (I have mariadb installed locally):

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u lc -p --protocol tcp
```

The issue rise when I try to use Docker secrets instead of explicitly writing **password** on the `docker-compose.yml` file.

## Working configuration

So, with this I can access mysql console:

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pw'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

## Issue

As soon as I move the secrets to a file, I cannot access anymore.

```
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ./env/mysql_root_password.tx
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

secrets:
  mysql_root_password:
    file: ./env/mysql_root_password.txt
```

The secrets work because the Wordpress container access it easily, so possibly the password `pw` is turned into something else when retrieved from a secret.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's very subtle...

If you are using file the environmental variable needs `_FILE` suffix!

`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` -> `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE`

Althoug it was a very silly mistake I'm not deleting the question as it might save someone else's time.